# JavaScript to add multiple decimal numbers and round the value after 0.59

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a script which will add multiple decimal numbers entered in input fields. But Here the value is rounding after **0.99** (*like price of item*). But I want to rounded it after **0.59**. (*like seconds*).

Please Help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".txt").each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });


    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }


<table width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
    <tr>
            <td>Sunday</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monday</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thrusday</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Saturday</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="summation">
            <td align="right">Sum :</td>
            <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want and what you have tried so far? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @chevybow thanks for reply!! I added my code over there. Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var functionName=function(a){
    var b=a-Math.floor(a);
    if(b>0.59)
    {
        a=Math.floor(a)+1;
    }
    else
    {
        a=Math.floor(a);
    }
return a;
}
```

And then in your script `sum=functionName(sum);`

Comment: thanks for the response Zlog.. but I wanna change the thing in my script i am trying to add my script in question. please check that and help me.